How to import JSON in MySQL on Windows
I want to import some objects with selected label:value pairs from a JSON (placed locally on a Windows machine) into MySQL (runs on the same Windows machine). MySQL is prepared for import - table with needed fields for values exists.
How would you do it, simple and reliable? In best case without Python.
I think about something like CMD/PowerShell/.bat, so I later can automatize the procedure with Windows Task Scheduler.
